# git-shell / git over SSH... telling remote server to perform a clone to itself

Tags: git, ssh, clone, git-shell

So I have SSH GIT access to a server of mine (which is using git-shell)

My question is, can I instruct that server (lets call it server A) to clone a repo remote from it (on a different server, lets call that server B) onto itself? So... have server A itself run something locally like

```
git clone https://serverb.com/example.git /serverAFolder/path/here
```

But send the command to run such a task remotely from my client Mac via SSH git-shell

-- Ideally i'd like something like

```
ssh gituser@servera.com git clone https://serverb.com/example.git /serverAFolder/path/here
```

But that doesn't seem to be allowed or working...

(My backup plan is to setup a simple bash script to do what I require inside the *~/git-shell-commands* folder to just run the command I require that way... but I was wondering if there was a better way first.)

Many thanks,

Comment: First find out how you clone locally when running on A (just use file paths instead of URLS) and then find out how to send this command from B to A.

Comment: Thats what I was worried the answer would be (i.e. use a different mechanism) -- it is not possible via git-shell?

Comment: I have no idea.  The mechanism is not different.  You just invoke the command remotely.  If you cannot do that your question needs improvement with more information.